# How to get only first class' data between two same classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, urllib

On https://www.hltv.org/matches page, matches divided by dates but the classes are same. I mean,

This is today's match class

```
<div class="match-day"><div class="standard-headline">2018-05-01</div>
```

This is tommorow's match class.

```
<div class="match-day"><div class="standard-headline">2018-05-02</div>
```

What i'm trying to do is, I wanna get the links under the "standard-headline" class but only today's matches. Like, getting the only first one.

Here is my code.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {}  # Headers gives information about you like your operation system, your browser etc.
headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0'  # I defined a user agent because HLTV perceive my connection as bot.
hltv = urllib.request.Request('https://www.hltv.org/matches', headers=headers)  # Basically connecting to website
session = urllib.request.urlopen(hltv)
sauce = session.read()  # Getting the source of website
soup = BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

matchlinks = []
# Getting the match pages' links.
for links in soup.find_all('div', class_='upcoming-matches'):  # Looking for "upcoming-matches" class in source.
    for links in soup.find_all('a'):  # Finding "a" tag under "upcoming-matches" class.
        clearlink = links.get('href')  # Getting the value of variable.
        if clearlink.startswith('/matches/'):  # Checking for if our link starts with "/matches/"
            matchlinks.append('https://hltv.org' + clearlink)  # Adding into list.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the website shows today's matches first (at the top), and then the next days'. So, if you want to get today's matches, you can simply use `find()`, which return the *first* match found.

Using this will give you what you want:

```
today = soup.find('div', class_='match-day')
```

---

But, if you want to explicitly specify the date, you can find the tag containing today's date, by using `text='2018-05-02'` as a parameter for the `find()` method. But, note that in the page source, the tag is `<span class="standard-headline">2018-05-02</span>` and not a `<div>` tag. After getting this tag, use [`.parent`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parent) to get the `<div class="match-day">` tag.

```
today = soup.find('span', text='2018-05-02').parent
```

---

Again, if you want to make the solution more generic, you can use `datetime.date.today()` instead of the hard-coded date.

```
today = soup.find('span', text=datetime.date.today()).parent
```

You'll have to import the `datetime` module for this.

Comment: It is insane to see that sometimes solution is so easy but you can't find or see it while you are too busy with it. Thank you. Btw, correct me if i am wrong but you find the span first than you get the div by using parent method right?