# How can i get the links under a specific class

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

So 2 days ago i was trying to parse the data between two same classes and Keyur helped me a lot then after he left other problems behind.. :D

[Page link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50120344/how-to-get-only-first-class-data-between-two-same-classes)

Now I want to get the links under a specific class, here is my code, and here are the errors.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import datetime

headers = {}  # Headers gives information about you like your operation system, your browser etc.
headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0'  # I defined a user agent because HLTV perceive my connection as bot.
hltv = urllib.request.Request('https://www.hltv.org/matches', headers=headers)  # Basically connecting to website
session = urllib.request.urlopen(hltv)
sauce = session.read()  # Getting the source of website
soup = BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

a = 0
b = 1
# Getting the match pages' links.
for x in soup.find('span', text=datetime.date.today()).parent:
    print(x.find('a'))
```

Error:

Actually there isn't any error but it outputs like:

```
None

None
None
-1
None
None
-1
```

Then i researched and saw that if there isn't any data to give, find function gives you nothing which is none.
Then i tried to use find_all

Code:

```
print(x.find_all('a'))
```

Output:

```
AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

This is the class name:

```
<div class="standard-headline">2018-05-01</div>
```

I don't want to post all the code to here so here is the link hltv.org/matches/ so you can check the classes more easily.

Comment: `import bs4 as BeautifulSoup` is not correct. What is your code actually like?

Comment: Did you accidentally or intentionally forget to mention that class name you talked about?

Comment: Do you mean `for a in soup.find('span', text=(datetime.date.today())).parent.find_all("a"): print(a)`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I am sorry for this, I was just watching some video and i didn't copy it, i wrote it manuel as last on my code. So it was wrong and i fixed it now, sorry. It wasn't my actual code. And also, yes your usage is correct, earliar i was going to try the same thing but i thought the code wouldn't work if i add something else to end of it as .find, it seems i was wrong. Your code works but it only pulls one link which i can loop .

Comment: @SIM it was accidentally. :')

Comment: Hey @PadraicCunningham i know these can be really easy questions but i literally don't get it. It only pulls one match, why? We do find_all and shouldn't it find all the a tags?

Comment: Under `standard-headline` class name there is no link. All of them are texts. At least I couldn't find one. Please be specific.

Comment: @SIM yes, what i want to do is trying to find the text which equals today's date and getting the data only under this specific class which i made it successfully but what i want to do now is to get the links under this specific class. Is it more clear now?

Comment: Let me remind you again there is no link under the class you have mentioned. I suppose, the links you wanna grab are within this compound classes `a-reset block upcoming-match standard-box`. Check it again and let me know. Btw, ain't this the headline under which those links sit `Upcoming CS:GO matches
2018-05-06`?

Comment: @akagna, i ran the code eariler and got a number of anchor tags returned so the code in the comment about should return more than one.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham when you run it without find_all code it gives you bunch of href as HTML but when you run it with find_all it only gives one. Can you check it :D

Comment: @SIM There isn't any data between span tags obviously but there is data at parent tag which is between divs. I didn't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I could understand what links OP really wants to grab. However, I took a guess. The links are within compound classes `a-reset block upcoming-match standard-box` and if you can spot the right class then one individual calss will suffice to fetch you the data like `selectors` do. Give it a shot.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import datetime

url = 'https://www.hltv.org/matches'

req = Request(url, headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}) 
res = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'lxml')
for links in soup.find(class_="standard-headline",text=(datetime.date.today())).find_parent().find_all(class_="upcoming-match")[:-2]: 
    print(urljoin(url,links.get('href')))
```

Output:

```
https://www.hltv.org/matches/2322508/yeah-vs-sharks-ggbet-ascenso
https://www.hltv.org/matches/2322633/team-australia-vs-team-uk-showmatch-csgo
https://www.hltv.org/matches/2322638/sydney-saints-vs-control-fe-lil-suzi-winner-esl-womens-sydney-open-finals
https://www.hltv.org/matches/2322426/faze-vs-astralis-iem-sydney-2018
https://www.hltv.org/matches/2322601/max-vs-fierce-tiger-starseries-i-league-season-5-asian-qualifier
```

and so on ------

Comment: But the point is to get only today's matches, I am already able to do this. Btw i liked how you shorten the code.

Comment: If you wished to grab for todays links only then the recent edit I've already made should get you there. Thanks.

Comment: Glad we both could sort it out eventually. Thanks.

Comment: You know SIM, everything is okay but why you used [:-2], i know what it does but I mean, why? :D

Comment: If you run the script without that indexing, you might get two extra links that you don't want. That is why I used that to satisfy your need. Thanks.